# How to disable drag space between two collections views in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using two collectionViews A and B one below the other. (I am using A to display headers and B containing the set of data below the header collection view A).

Now when I scroll the Collection view B to top and reach the end point I get a gap between A and B, which is not the expected output behaviour. What should I do to make A drag along with B without any space while scrolling.

TLDR - I've added a gif showing the issue.

[image: Gap between the two collection views]

```
 func configureHeaderCollectionView() {
        headerCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
        view.addSubview(headerCollectionView)
        headerCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        headerCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        headerCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        headerCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        headerCollectionView.delegate = self
        headerCollectionView.dataSource = self
        headerCollectionView.register(CustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "header")
    }
    
    func configureCollectionView() {
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerCollectionView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(CustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CustomCollectionViewCell.identifier)
    }
```

I am calling these two functions in viewDidLoad to setup the collection views.

Comment: How about disabling bouncing of the collection views?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619383-alwaysbouncevertical

Comment: Did you try to set the size of the anchor between the 2 collectionView to 0 ?

Comment: Yes, It is already set to 0. I haven't added any constants.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with a simpler GUI.

Try to disable scrolling of collectionView. This will not disable scrolling of cells, headers and footer.

```
collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
```